# Server/NAS system for private usage

Tags: server, nas

as a new project I want to establish a home server/NAS solution at my home.

I want to fulfill following requirements:

- The solution shall host an application server which runs an Jira instance (nothing to big, maybe 2-5 Users, manage small own projects regarding own software coding projects)
- The solution shall host an own DB server (something like mySQL or postgres, also only for own occasional usage, e.g. handling a DB for financial income/outcome, so no huge data space and workload is expected)
- The solution shall fulfill a classical NAS usage, like do automatic backup of photos and documents from different computers in the household
- The solution shall be reachable 24/7, so a low power consumption shall be accounted
- Jira instance/DB instances and data like photos/documents shall be online (not just within my home network, but also outside)
- The hardware shall cost below 400€

Which hardware should I buy? I am a little bit scared that I buy a to low powered solution. I favor a NAS solution of synology like this one
https://www.synology.com/de-de/products/DS218
But I am not sure that I can run the mentioned applications (Jira, DB server) on it.
Do this NAS products provide an OS or do they only provide data space?
Do I do it right that I reasearch for NAS solutions or am I on the wrong path here?

Thanks for your answers
SpiderTom89